# basic thing from a job interview - using linked list,arrays

Tags: arrays, linked-list

I got this question on a job interview, and i could't solve it.
 i think i was just really nervous because it doesn't look this hard.

> Arr is a given integer array, size n.   Sol is a given empty array,
>   size n.
>
> for each i (i goes from 0 to n-1 ) you have to put in Sol[i] the index
>   in Arr of the closest elemnt appears on the left side, that is smaller
>   than Arr[i].   meaning: Sol[i]=max{ j | j < i; Arr[j] < Arr[i] }.   if
>   the is no such index, put -1.
>
> for example: Arr is [5,7,9,2,8,11,16,10,12]   Sol is
>   [-1,0,1,-1,3,4,5,4,7]
>
> time complexity: o(n) space complexity: o(n)

I tried to scan the array from the end to the start, but I didn't know how to continue.

I was asked to use only array and linked list.
I had 10 minutes to solve it, so guess it is not that hard.

thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that for Arr[] with length < 2 there are trivial solutions.  This pseudo code assumes that Arr[] has a length >= 2.

```
int Arr[] = {5,7,9,2,8,11,16,10,12};
int Sol[] = new int[9];

Stack<int> undecided;   // or a stack implemented using a linked list

Sol[0] = -1;    // this is a given

for(int i = Arr.length() - 1; i != 0; --i) {
    undecided.push(i); // we haven't found a smaller value for this Arr[i] item yet
                       // note that all the items already on the stack (if any)
                       // are smaller than the value of Arr[i] or they would have
                       // been popped off in a previous iteration of the loop
                       // below

    while (!undecided.empty() && (Arr[i-1] < Arr[undecided.peek()])) {
        // the value for the item on the undecided stack is
        //  larger than Arr[i-1], so that's the index for 
        //  the item on the undecided stack
        Sol[undecided.peek()] = i-1;
        undecided.pop();
    }
}

// We've filled in Sol[] for all the items have lesser values to
//  the left of them.  Whatever is still on the undecided stack
//  needs to be set to -1 in Sol

while (!undecided.empty()) {
    Sol[undecided.peek()] = -1;
    undecided.pop();
}
```

To be honest, I'm not sure I would have come up with this in an interview situation given a 10 minute time limit.

A C++ version of this can be found on ideone.com: https://ideone.com/VXC0yq

Comment: hi again, i looked at it again, and i dont understand why it is O(n).
we have 2 loops (while in a for),and it looks like O(n^2) on the worth case.

Comment: The first loop goes through the list once, the second loop goes through a list that has at most the same number of elements once.  That's 2n which is still O(n).  The very last loop (that sets things to -1) can be eliminated entirely by initializing the `Sol[]1 array to -1.  It also adds at most one walk through of the list so I think a worst case analysis is visiting elements 3n times.

Comment: If you put a counter in the program that increments at each of the 3 loops you'll see that the total number of loop iterations is 2n.

Comment: OK i think i got it. i push every element only once and pop it only once. thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
    int Arr[] = {5,7,9,2,8,11,16,10,12};
    int Sol[] = new int[9];

    for(int i = 0; i < Arr.length; i++) {
        int element = Arr[i];

        int tmp = -1;
        for(int j = 0 ;j < i; j++) {
            int other = Arr[j];
            if (other < element) {
                tmp = j;                    
            }
        }

        Sol[i] = tmp;           
    }
```

Comment: That doesn't look O(n) to me.